# Available SSD disk space shrinking within seconds

Tags: ssd, macos, disk-space

My SSD's available disk space of my MacMini Late 2012 is shrinking within seconds. CleanMyMac says 'Others''s size is increasing. I have no idea what is happening and am wondering why there is so few free space on my Mac. I am not downloading anything (as far as I know).

Here is my activity monitor's 'Disk' tab:
[image: activity monitor]

...and the 'Memory' tab:
[image: activity monitor #2]

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

PS: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WGj4UPuAaU) you can see the process. (It's not sped up, real time!)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Activity Monitor -> disk or/and memory

Comment: Did so, sorry for German language.

Comment: I'm german so it's no problem ;-). Please also add a screenshot of the memory/Speicher tab (also sorted)

Comment: Ach supi :D - Added it, thanks for trying to help :)